# Google Sign-In Pops up and closes Immediately after

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Just to make this clear, I am referring to this google sign as there are multiple: [Google Sign-In for your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

I have both the meta tag and script tag in the header of my page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="[ThatsWhereMyIDIs].apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

as well as the div element for the Sign-In within my body:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" onclick="console.log('yay');"></div>
```

I used the 'yay' to check if the element was triggered, and it is, however the "data-onsuccess" is never called.

What could be the reason for that and furthermore, how do I fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but only when I deploy. It works in a local server. I think it is because it requires **https** and I do not have that for the server I am testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @stahlmanDesign. However, that doesn't seem to be the problem for me :/